# WebPlayer modificavel com JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou criando uma pagina "WebPlayer" e preciso de duas coisas nela:

- 1: Uma lista com os EPS que ao clicar mude o link dentro do embed
  "video"
- 2: Função para manipular o embed "video" e redirecionar o link    dele
  a partir de um JS...

Esse é meu atual HTML/JS... [Não trabalhei nada da primeira função ainda... Pois preciso ter certeza que a segunda trabalha bem]

```html
<html>
<div id="lista">
<embed src="https://six-ratings.000webhostapp.com/FO.htm"></embed>
</div>
<div id="video">
<embed src="http://showpl.tk/c5283"></embed>
</div>
<style>
#lista{
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    height: 25%;
}
#video{
    position: relative;
    top: -160px;
    left: 30%;
    display: -webkit-box;
}
</style>
<script>
var x.document.getElementById("video");
var tag= x.document.querySelector("video source").src;
   location.href=tag;
   window.locationf=tag;
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Vou ver o mesmo e reporto o que descobrir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você utilizar *attr* do jQuery para criar suas playlists, por exemplo:

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551859/html-5-video-or-audio-playlist)

```js
$(function() {
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
        $("#videoarea").attr({
            "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
            "poster": "",
            "autoplay": "autoplay"
        })
    })
    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
    })
})
```

```css
#playlist {
    display:table;
}
#playlist li{
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:8px;
}

#playlist li:hover{
    color:blue;                        
}
#videoarea {
    float:left;
    width:640px;
    height:480px;
    margin:10px;    
    border:1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="" src=""></video>

<ul id="playlist">
    <li movieurl="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/happyfit2.mp4" moviesposter="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg">Happy Fit</li>
    <li movieurl="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4">Sintel</li>          
    <li movieurl="http://html5example.net/static/video/html5_Video_VP8.webm">Resident Evil</li>      
    <li movieurl="http://www.ioncannon.net/examples/vp8-webm/big_buck_bunny_480p.webm">Big Buck Bunny</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Funcionou... Obrigado cara...

Comment: Amigo... Tem como fixar a lista dentro de algo que limite o espaço da mesma... Tipo como fazemos com um <embed>... Pois está indo até o horizonte e fica difícil ter que ir la em baixo clicar no lo link e depois voltar para ver o video... [Este é o link da minha pagina ( https://six-ratings.000webhostapp.com/WebApp/APP.html )]